# positive random number matrix gives only 0 and negative in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, random, integer

I need to make a 100x100 matrix with only odd integer random numbers, but it only gives me zeros and negative numbers.
Something like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 61 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
605810241 32763 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 -1109404240  -1109404223 46 -1109404000 46 -1109404196 46 -1109404200 46 0 0 0 0 0 1204 0 0 141694856 367 32 3
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int matrix[100][100];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100;)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100;)
        {
            int random = 1 + rand() % 100;
            if (random % 2 != 0 && random > 0)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = random;
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j]
                 << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
```

Comment: Your loops are wrong, filling only diagonal and leaving most of the matrix filled with garbage.

Comment: If I was tasked with generating odd numbers I'd to it something like this: `random = 1 + 2 * (rand() % 50);`. That uses each value returned by `rand()`, rather than discarding values that don't fit the criterion. There's nothing inherently wrong with skipping values that don't fit (and for some distributions it's essential), but for something this simple it's faster to not throw away values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only odd value, you can do it explicitly with `random |= 1;`.
And with this, you can remove the `if` statement and modify the loop to ordinary shape (likes your output loop).

And mistake will disappear automatically, like:

```
for( int i=0; i<100; ++i )
{
    for( int j=0; j<100; ++j )
    {
        matrix[i][j] = ( rand() % 100 ) | 1;  //always odd
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry to bother you again, why is the |1 doing exactly? or is it just a parameter for the "rand () " function, just to keep it in mind, all the information I found was about bitwise operations and I don't really know what that has to do with the "rand ()".

Comment: Strudying about bit format of (positive) integer, you will find that the LSB is corresponding to "even or odd". Bit patterns with LSB=1 are odd value. So, when the positive integer value `random` obtained from rand() is even, `random | 1` becomes to the odd value(equals to `random + 1`).
When the `random` is already odd, `random | 1` cause no change(It becomes to `random`).

Comment: A simpler implementation would be `if( (random%2)==0 ){ ++random; }`. Using bit operation is just one way. Important point is "If you want odd value, create odd value straightforwardly will be good". (Retrying from `rand()` may never finish if you are unlucky!?)

Comment: Another simple implementation would be `rand() % 50 * 2 + 1`.

Comment: Yes, your way (use `rand` to get the index of the odd value sequence) is good(simple, easy to understand) too.